# how to analyse the data of a single data table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have a table HO_TRAN where 5 years data is stored about a transaction. table consists of fields like Season_id, farmer_id, plot_no, Net_weight.
Season id is of Year of transaction
farmer_id is of consumer ID
Plot_no are the unique no.s of plots farmers have.
net_weight is the product supplied by farmer to us by various his plots.

what i need is to analyse(compare) 2 years data by farmer_id, means i want to filter the farmer_id who has supplied both years and who is not.I am confused how to design SQL query for this. i want output in this manner

```
     Farmer_id | Plot_no | Net_weight 

     1         | 123     | 5.00
               | 321     | 15.00
     2         | 456     | 6.00
               | 159     | 65.00
               | 187     | 56.00
     3         | 642     | 47.00
```

Comment: can you share table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two years in mind, say YEAR1 and YEAR2, then you can use analytic functions for this purpose:

```
select Farmer_id, Plot_no, Net_weight 
from (select ht.*,
             max(case when season = YEAR1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by farmer_id) as year1,
             max(case when season = YEAR2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by farmer_id) as year2
      from HO_TRAN ht
     ) ht
where year1 = 1 and year2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Farmer_id, Plot_no, Net_weight
from HO_TRAN as ht
where exists (
      select 1 from HO_TRAN
      where Farmer_id = ht.Farmer_id
      and year between X and Y
      group by Farmer_id
      having count(distinct year) = 2
);
```

Or something like that, depending on what you actually mean.  You say you want to analyze and compare, across years, but there's no year in your proposed results.